# How to save emailed video into Photos program?

Tags: photos, video, library

I'm just now getting used to Photos. When someone emails me a video, I can't just drag it into my photos library like I could with iPhoto. How do I add it to my existing library?

Answer (score 1):

**Save Attachment**

1. Right click the video in Mail.
2. Select "Save Attachment".
3. Go to where you saved it in Finder.
4. Drag it into Photos.

It may take it a while, depending on the age of your Mac, how big the video is, etc.

Comment: OK, that seems like a clunky way of doing things, unlike previously where you could just select "import to iphotos" directly from the mail program...so there is no short cut any longer?

Comment: @Meg No, there's nothing like that.